# build array in array in loop

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code! I'm trying to get from `$test` array and at end show me   like `$final` array! tnx to help! code should get domain name and show how many time a userid has been repeated!

```
<?php

$test = array(
 array(
    'id' => 1,
    'domain' => 'google.com',
    'userid' => "123"
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'domain' => 'google.com',
    'userid' => "456"enter 
),
array(
    'id' => 3,
    'domain' => 'yahoo.com',
    'userid' => "456"
),
array(
    'id' => 4,
    'domain' => 'google.com',
    'userid' => "123"
),
array(
    'id' => 5,
    'domain' => 'bing.com',
    'userid' => "128"
)
);
$i=0;
 foreach ($test as $items) {
 $domains[$i]=$items['domain'];
 $userid[$i]=$items['userid'];
 $i++;
}
$domain=array_unique($domains);
$domain1 = array_values($domain);
print_r($domain);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';
$d=1; $tedad = 1;
while($d<=4){
    $b = 1 ; $c=0;
    while ($test[$b]['id']<=4) {
        if($test[$b]['domain'] == $domain1[$d])
        {
            $temp = $test[$b]['userid'];
            if(/*$test[$b]['userid'] !==*/ !array_key_exists($domain1[$d]   ['userid']){
                //$domain1[$d] = array($test[$b]['userid'] => $tedad) ; 
                echo $temp;
                $end = array(
                $domain1[$d] => array(
                $temp => $tedad )
                );

            }
            else{
                $end[$d][$test[$b]['userid']]= $end[$d][$test[$b]['userid']] +1;

        }
        }
        else{
            $b++;

        }

 }  
  $d++; $tedad = 1;
 }

 print_r($end);
$final = array(
 "google.com" => array(
    "123" => 2,
    "456" => 1
),
"yahoo.com" => array(
    "456" => 1
)
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$test = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'domain' => 'google.com',
    'userid' => "123"
),
array(
    'id' => 2,
    'domain' => 'google.com',
    'userid' => "456"
),
array(
    'id' => 3,
    'domain' => 'yahoo.com',
    'userid' => "456"
),
array(
    'id' => 4,
    'domain' => 'google.com',
    'userid' => "123"
)
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';

$domains = array();
foreach ($test as $value) {
if (!in_array($value['domain'], $domains))
    $domains[$value['domain']] = array();
}
foreach ($domains as $key => $domain) {
foreach ($test as $item) {
    if ($key == $item['domain']) {
        if (isset($domains[$key][$item['userid']])) {
            $domains[$key][$item['userid']] = $domains[$key]      [$item['userid']]+1;
        } else {
            $domains[$key][$item['userid']] = 1;
        }
    }
   }
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($domains);
 echo '</pre>';
  echo '<hr>';

   // $final = array(
 //     "google.com" => array(
  //        "123" => 2,
   //       "456" => 1
  //    ),
   //   "yahoo.com" => array(
 //         "456" => 1
 //     )
 // );

  // echo '<pre>';
 // print_r($final);
 // echo '</pre>';
 // echo '<hr>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = array();
foreach($test as $t)
{
    if(isset($result[$t['domain']][$t['userid']]))
        $result[$t['domain']][$t['userid']]++;
    else $result[$t['domain']][$t['userid']] = 1;
}
```

If you don't want to include some domains use like:

```
$result = array();
foreach($test as $t)
{
    if($t['domain'] == 'bing.com')
         continue;

    if(isset($result[$t['domain']][$t['userid']]))
        $result[$t['domain']][$t['userid']]++;
    else $result[$t['domain']][$t['userid']] = 1;
}
```